# Facing issue while creating an attachment in JIRA with webMethods client

Tags: jira-rest-api, webmethods

We're facing an issue (http response 415 trying to create an attachment in JIRA). Can you please help resolve our issue? Steps we followed in webMethods

1) getFile load as stream
2) pub.mime:createMimeData
3) pub.mime:addBodyPart (pass the stream from step1 as input, and not setting the content type; we've tried setting application/octet-stream with same results ).
4) pub.mime:getEnvelopeStream.
5) pub.io:streamToString (to verify the Mime created in step 4)
6) pub.client:http (passing envStream creted from step4 to data/mimeStream and loadAs "stream"

Step5 output

Message-ID: <508725916.27.1498892350039.JavaMail.webmethods@bisawswmindv01>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="------defined------";name=file;filename=sample.txt
X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck
Authorization: Basic d2AiobWV0aG9kczpBMTJzcjcxYmI=

------=_Part_26_16733932.1498892350039
Message-ID: <1774613176.25.1498892350038.JavaMail.webmethods@bisawswmindv01>
MIME-Version: 1.0
content-type: text/plain
content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
this is a test file: this is a test file

------=_Part_26_16733932.1498892350039--

Answer (score 0):

415 error code is for Unsupported Media Type means,
The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.

Looks like media type of the attachment you are uploading is not supported by JIRA.